# Getting byte array from C into C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, unmanaged

I have the following C function that I need to call from C#:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int receive_message(char* ret_buf, int buffer_size);
```

I've declared the following on the C# side:

```
[DllImport("MyCLibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "receive_message")]
public static extern int ReceiveMessage([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder retBuf, int bufferSize);
```

I'm calling the function like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int len = ReceiveMessage(sb, 512);
```

This works fine with my initial tests where I was receiving "string" messages.  But, now I want to receive packed messages (array of chars/bytes).  The problem is that the array of chars/bytes will have 0s and will terminate the string so I don't get back the whole message.  Any ideas how I can refactor to get array of bytes back?

Comment: Use Marshal.Copy(IntPtr source, byte[] destination, int startIndex, int length).

Comment: @jdweng, I'm not following.  Do I need to change my extern declaration in my C#?

Comment: You are fibbing about the *bufferSize* argument, the Capacity of that StringBuilder is 0.  The heap corruption that this can cause can be very unpleasant.  If it is not actually a string then you *must* declare the 1st argument as byte[] instead.  And same thing, pass its Length property as the 2nd argument.

Comment: I did notice my memory was slowly growing...maybe that was why.  I think I figured out the Marshall.Copy that jdweng recommended.  I'll post full answer once I confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jdweng help, I've changed the declaration to:

```
[DllImport("MyCLibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "receive_message")]
public static extern int ReceiveMessage(IntPtr retBuf, int bufferSize);
```

And, I'm allocating and freeing the memory on the C# side along with marshalling the data.

```
IntPtr pnt = Marshall.AllocHGlobal(512);
try
{
   int len = ReceiveMessage(pnt, 512);
   ...
   byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
   Marshal.Copy(pnt, bytes, 0, len);
   ...
}
finally
{
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
}
```